# How to trigger remote job from pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to trigger a job in the remote Jenkins host and wait for it.
I also want to get some of artifacts (Maybe I will use RestAPI call)

How can I trigger remote job?

```
node {
    stage('Trigger remote build-job') {
        sh "echo 'wait until remote job finish'"
        buildRemote ('https://jenkins.linecorp.com', 'apk_builder')
    }

    stage('Download from buildServer to testServer') {
        build 'android_monkey_apk_downloader'
    }

    stage('Installing') {
        build 'android_monkey_apk_installer'
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin [Parameterized Remote Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger) should handle your need.

[The documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/) explains how to use it in a Jenkins Pipeline with the `triggerRemoteJob` step.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, very clear documentation on generating pipeline script: https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/screenshots/pipelineSyntaxGenerator.png